# Knockout.js 3.3.0 options binding for jQuery mobile 1.4 select

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js 3.3.0 with jQuery mobile 1.4.
The problem using knockout.js together with jQuery mobile is that the programmatically changes to the underlying viewmodel are not always reflected to the graphical user interface, due to the JQM refactoring of the html elements, or widgets. So, for example, the JQM selectmenu is  synchronized from the user interface to the viewmodel, but not in the other way.

I'm trying to stick together the 3.3.0 KO 'options' binding with a custombinding to the current JQM actual version.
There are already two possible solutions for the 'refresh' problem already proposed at SO for 2.x versions of KO: jqmSelect and jqmValue, as custombindings.
I try this suggestions for a more recent KO+JQM combination, putting together all the answers/comments found at SO regarding this topic.

This is the js that i'm using to test:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonResultData = [{
        "id": 6,
            "name": "First item",
            "pattern": "Cheetah"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "name": "Second item",
            "pattern": "Viper"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
            "name": "Third item",
            "pattern": "Scorpion"
    }];
    ko.applyBindings(new AdminViewModel(jsonResultData));
});

function Match(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.pattern = ko.observable(data.pattern);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}

function AdminViewModel(allData) {
    var self = this;
    self.matches = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.matchesFromDb = $.map(allData, function (item) {
        return new Match(item);
    });
    self.matches = self.matchesFromDb;
    self.selectedMatchId = ko.observable(self.matches[0].id());
    self.selectedMatch = ko.observable(self.matches[0]);
    self.setSelectedMatchId = function (match) {
        if (match.id() != self.selectedMatchId()) {
            self.selectedMatchId(match.id());
            self.selectedMatch(match);
        }
    };
    self.patternValues = ko.observableArray(["Shark", "Viper", "Chameleon", "Cheetah", "Scorpion"]);
}
```

I made a fiddle to test the jqmValue custom binding, which is one of the latest soultions found at SO, but but i'm not able to get it to work:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        if (typeof ko.bindingHandlers.value.init !== 'undefined') {
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var instance;
        if (typeof ko.bindingHandlers.value.update !== 'undefined') {
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
        }
        instance = $.data(element, 'mobile-selectmenu');
        if (instance) {
            $(element).selectmenu('refresh', true);
        }
    }
};
```

(the original code for AdminViewModel as reference for KO 2.x thanks to pablo is working with the suggested change to invert value/options in the markup thanks to JohnEarles at google groups)

Here is the fiddle with actual KO and JQM versions where i try to include the best of all suggestions found regarding this topic:

http://jsfiddle.net/nHNzL/42/

but i'm still streching my hairs without success. Why in my test fiddle the changes to the viewmodel are not reflected to the JQM selectmenu? What is my error?

**UPDATE**: two-page fiddle to test also initialization: http://jsfiddle.net/nHNzL/50/

**FINAL VERSION:**
I made 2 small fixes and 1 change:
1) isInstance shall be checked every time
2) removed the if (currentValue == value)
3) inverted the disabled attribute
Moreover: i tested this custombinding in a ko foreach-loop, each select element needs to be child of an own container div.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmSelectMenu = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor()),
            valueObservable = allBindings.get("value"), valueSubscription,
            optionsObservable = allBindings.get("options"), optionsSubscription;
        var refresh = function () { 
            var $el = $(element);
            var isInstance = !!$.data(element, 'mobile-selectmenu');
            if (isInstance) {
                $el.selectmenu('refresh', true); 
            } else {
                /* instantiate the widget unless jqm has already done so */
                $(element).selectmenu(options);
            }
        };
        refresh();

        /* hook up to the observables that make up the underlying <select> */
        if (ko.isSubscribable(valueObservable)) {
            valueSubscription = valueObservable.subscribe(refresh);
        }
        if (ko.isSubscribable(optionsObservable)) {
            optionsSubscription = optionsObservable.subscribe(refresh);
        }

        /* properly dispose of widgets & subscriptions when element is removed */
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).selectmenu("destroy");
            if (valueSubscription) valueSubscription.dispose();
            if (optionsSubscription) optionsSubscription.dispose();
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor()),
            $el = $(element);

        /* update any widget options if necessary */
        ko.utils.objectForEach(options, function (key, value) {
            if (key === "enabled") {
                $el.selectmenu(value ? "enable" : "disable");
            } else {
                $el.selectmenu("option", key, value);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you are mixing two separate things.

1. There is the underlying `<select>` element. It holds the available options as well as the selected one.
2. Then there is the jQuery Mobile `SelectMenu` widget. It is concerned with the UX part. A look at [the API options](https://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/) it provides reveals that it really has not a lot to do with the underlying select box, mostly using it for self-initialization.

Of course the widget communicates a value change to the underlying select box, but when you change the value programmatically you must communicate that to the widget yourself, by calling `refresh` on it. So even without knockout this is not a two-way communication.

We *do* have set of knockout built-in bindings that work very well with select boxes, but what we *don't* have is a binding that communicates changes in those values to the widget. What we also don't have is a way of initializing/updating any of the widget's API options.

So instead of re-inventing the `value` binding we need one that deals with the widget itself and otherwise simply complements the existing bindings:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmSelectMenu = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor()),
            valueObservable = allBindings.get("value"), valueSubscription,
            optionsObservable = allBindings.get("options"), optionsSubscription,
            isInstance = !!$.data(element, 'mobile-selectmenu'),
            refresh = function () { $(element).selectmenu('refresh', true); };

        // instantiate the widget unless jqm has already done so
        if (!isInstance) $(element).selectmenu(options);
        refresh();

        // hook up to the observables that make up the underlying <select>
        if (ko.isSubscribable(valueObservable)) {
            valueSubscription = valueObservable.subscribe(refresh);
        }
        if (ko.isSubscribable(optionsObservable)) {
            optionsSubscription = optionsObservable.subscribe(refresh);
        }

        // properly dispose of widgets & subscriptions when element is removed
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).selectmenu("destroy");
            if (valueSubscription) valueSubscription.dispose();
            if (optionsSubscription) optionsSubscription.dispose();
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor()),
            $elem = $(element);

        // update any widget options if necessary
        ko.utils.objectForEach(options, function (key, value) {
            var currentValue = $elem.selectmenu("option", key);
            if (currentValue !== value) {
                if (key === "disabled") {
                    $elem.selectmenu(value ? "disable" : "enable");
                } else {
                    $elem.selectmenu("option", key, value);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I have written this in the spirit of the [knockout-jQueryUI](http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/). I recommend taking a look at that library.

Here's an updated fiddle, too. http://jsfiddle.net/nHNzL/46/

Comment: this is great, and i have a lot to learn from you, but when i look in your updated fiddle at the viewmodel, it says: "selectedPattern": "Shark" but the selectmenu always shows "Select...".
Regarding the great library knockout-jQuery-UI, you mean it could be used for inspiration/easily adapted to JQM, or that could be also used for JQM as-is?

Comment: The style could certainly be adopted, if you take the time to understand its architecture. As I said, my code roughly follows the same principle, but knockout-jQueryUI certainly is a lot more polished. As to the error, I was missing one initial call to `refresh`, compare [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30003775/revisions#rev-arrow-5c4c8b96-8951-48b9-8831-14d5a3cc4ba7).

Comment: For example, notice how the checkbox widget in the Fiddle communicates the value to its underlying `<input>` when you click it, where the change is picked up by knockout and disables/enables the selectmenu widget (though `ko.bindingHandlers.jqmSelectMenu.update()`). When you change the `<input>` value with JS, the checkbox widget won't notice. For that you would need a `jqmCheckbox` binding that calls `refresh` for you, and it would look *very* similar to the `jqmSelectMenu` binding above.

Comment: The 'disabled' option you introduced reveals that there is additional complexity in the combination KO+JQM, for exmple: the first time you set the 'disabled' option, the ui-popup doesn't show, but after this has been shown for the first time, setting the 'disabled' option again has the effect to disable the selection inside the ui-popup container. 
Also the initialization with 'if (!isInstance) $(element).selectmenu(options);' is not enough, if executed, the ui-popup it appears semi-transparent. well... not so easy

Comment: That's odd. In fact *all* the options the widget supports are also supported by the binding. I included the disabled option only to show this by example. In any case, the binding does not do anything you wouldn't do in manual jQuery code, so I don't quite understand why it misbehaves. I'll look into it later.

Comment: @deblocker Obviously `.selectmenu("option", "disabled", true)` does not do the same thing as `.selectmenu("disable")`. \*sigh\* See [my last edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30003775/revisions#rev-arrow-fdf3cff6-573c-446b-a68f-07cc20a5b86c).

Comment: thx for this, i updated the fiddle with a two-pages structure, where the list and the select are on the second page: http://jsfiddle.net/nHNzL/49/ this requires another custombinding for the listview on the top, unlike the one-page test. As i said, if you open the popup, the popup has been not fully initialized, maybe because its not a data-native-menu.
All these issues leads me to a more strategical question: shall we use the custombinding init function to keep JQM in sync, especially when there will be a very big ViewModel?

Comment: sorry for my imprecision in my previous comment above, i mean: the popup has been not fully enhanced. setting data-theme="a" in the select tag solved this issue. I updated the fiddle in my question.

Comment: I have not had the time to look into this again, sorry for not getting back to you earlier, I still have the whole thing open as a tab somewhere. I'm not too familiar with the intricacies of jQuery Mobile, so it's a bit of hacking for me as well. The manner in which I instantiate the widget in the binding `init` strikes me as unclean, I'm just not sure how to do it better.